# can 64 bit MS office install be rolled back to 32 on Win 8.1 64 bit machine

Tags: excel, 64-bit

I've learned that 64bit Office isn't backwards compatible.
I'm not a programmer (VBA etc) and don't know where to start to re=write some macros to get them to run in the 64 bit version of Excel

I don't have a 32bit version accessible to install. I do have access to the original install files.

Can the 64bit version be rolled back to 32bit

Comment: They are two seperate things: if you want to install 32-bit Office, use the 32-bit installer. If you want to install 64-bit Office, use the 64-bit installer. I believe activations and serial keys and such are valid for both bitnesses. But I wonder what exactly is the code that is failing for you. Have you tried using the 64-bit version? What was the result?

Comment: I have been using the 64bit version for a little while. Having revisited to update some older files created with the 32 bit version I learned now that they won't work. Also some helper addins that I used with them won't work ... i.e. ASAP Utilities doesn't support the 64 bit version. If I knew how to write (re-write)the macros ... but don't I'm not a programmer and I'm learning OTJ. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You need the 32-bit version of office to install it.  If your installation package has the 32-bit binaries you can simply uninstall the 64-bit version and install the 32-bit version in its place.

The way to get the 32-bit code to work is to add the `PtrSafe` attribute to your calls to external, 32-bit libraries.  For example:
`Public Declare PtrSafe Function Lib "externalLib32" Alias "libFunc" (ByVal Arg As Variant) As Variant`